# How can I reload the table schema in sequel?

Tags: ruby, sequel

Given I have the following migration:

```
Sequel.migration do
  up do
    alter_table :users do
      add_column :is_admin, :default => false
    end

    # Sequel runs a DESCRIBE table statement, when the model is loaded.
    # At this point, it does not know that users have a is_admin flag.
    # So it fails.

    @user = User.find(:email => "admin@fancy-startup.example")
    @user.is_admin = true
    @user.save!
  end
end
```

Then sequel does not automatically reload the table structure (see comment inline).

I am using this ugly hack to work around it:

```
# deep magic begins here. If you remove a single line, it will
# break the migration.

User.db.schema("users", :reload => true)
User.instance_variable_set(:@db_schema, nil)
User.columns
User.new.respond_to?(:is_admin=)
sleep 1
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Much simpler than your hack is this hack: (re)set the dataset to the table name:

```ruby
User.set_dataset :users
```

Seen in action:

```ruby
require 'sequel'
DB = Sequel.sqlite
DB.create_table :users do
  primary_key :id
  String :name
end

class User < Sequel::Model; end
User << { name:"Bob" }

DB.alter_table :users do
  add_column :is_admin, :boolean, default:false
end

p User.first       #=> #<User @values={:id=>1, :name=>"Bob", :is_admin=>false}>

p User.setter_methods    #=> ["name="]
User.set_dataset :users  # Make the magic happen
p User.setter_methods    #=> ["name=", "is_admin="]

@user = User.first
@user.is_admin = true
@user.save

p User.first       #=> #<User @values={:id=>1, :name=>"Bob", :is_admin=>true}>
```

*<sub>Note that [there is no `Sequel::Model#save!` method](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Model/InstanceMethods.html); I changed it to `save` so that it would work.</sub>*

Comment: Thank you! By the way: I wrote a monkey patch that adds `save!` in my version of sequel, that raises an exception, while `save` just returns true and false. So it works for me :)